# Solve & Simplify statistical equation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Fermi energy is:
$e_f^{3/2}=\mu^{3/2}(1+\frac{\pi^2}{8 \beta^2\mu^2}+..)$

From this equataion in the textbook obtained:
$\mu=e_f(1-\frac{\pi^2}{12\beta^2 e_f^2}+..)$

How?! I'm really confused.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$e_f^{3/2}=\mu^{3/2}\left(1+\frac{\pi^2}{8 \beta^2\mu^2}+\cdots\right)\implies e_f=\mu\left(1+\frac{\pi^2}{8 \beta^2\mu^2}+\cdots\right)^{2/3}$$ Now, using the generalized binomial theorem or Taylor expansion  for large values of $\mu$
$$\left(1+\frac{\pi^2}{8 \beta^2\mu^2}+\cdots\right)^{2/3}=1+\frac{\pi ^2}{12 \beta ^2 \mu ^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{\mu^3 }\right)$$ But, at the very first order $\mu\approx e_f$ and so $$e_f\approx \mu \left(1+\frac{\pi ^2}{12 \beta ^2 e_f ^2}\right)\implies \mu\approx\frac {e_f} {1+\frac{\pi ^2}{12 \beta ^2 e_f ^2 }}\approx e_f\left(1-\frac{\pi ^2}{12 \beta ^2 e_f ^2}\right)$$

Comment: You could also put the two steps in one, $\mu=e_f(1+\frac18h)^{-2/3}=e_f(1-\frac1{12}h+\frac5{288}h^2\mp…)$.

Comment: @LutzL. There are so mpany ways to do it ... !